# Directx error DrawTextA and LPCSTR and HDC

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9, lpcstr

in Debug mode I get this:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2660   'DrawTextA': function does not take 4 arguments Win32Project6   c:\users\dani\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\win32project6\win32project6\hacks.cpp   41

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2065   'i': undeclared identifier  Win32Project6   c:\users\dani\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\win32project6\win32project6\hacks.cpp   53

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       IntelliSense: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "HDC"  Win32Project6   c:\Users\Dani\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Hacks.cpp   41

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       IntelliSense: argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCSTR"    Win32Project6   c:\Users\Dani\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Hacks.cpp   41
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       IntelliSense: argument of type "D3DCOLOR" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPRECT"   Win32Project6   c:\Users\Dani\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Hacks.cpp   41
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call    Win32Project6   c:\Users\Dani\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Hacks.cpp   41

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2065   'i': undeclared identifier  Win32Project6   c:\users\dani\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\win32project6\win32project6\hacks.cpp   53

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2228   left of '.name' must have class/struct/union    Win32Project6   c:\users\dani\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\win32project6\win32project6\hacks.cpp   53


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2228   left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union   Win32Project6   c:\users\dani\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\win32project6\win32project6\hacks.cpp   53
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2660   'DrawTextA': function does not take 4 arguments Win32Project6   c:\users\dani\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\win32project6\win32project6\hacks.cpp   53

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       IntelliSense: identifier "i" is undefined   Win32Project6   c:\Users\Dani\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Hacks.cpp   53


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       IntelliSense: argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCSTR"    Win32Project6   c:\Users\Dani\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Hacks.cpp   53

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       IntelliSense: argument of type "D3DCOLOR" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPRECT"   Win32Project6   c:\Users\Dani\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Hacks.cpp   53


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call    Win32Project6   c:\Users\Dani\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project6\Win32Project6\Hacks.cpp   53
```

CODe for Hacks.cpp

```
    #include "Hacks.h"

    int MenuIndex;

    D3DCOLOR fontRed = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
    D3DCOLOR fontGreen = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 0, 255, 0);
    D3DCOLOR fontBlue = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 0, 0, 255);
    D3DCOLOR fontWhite = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
    D3DCOLOR fontBlack = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);

    void Hacks::CreateFont(IDirect3DDevice9 *d3dDevice, std::string choiceFont)
    {
        D3DXCreateFont(d3dDevice, 20, 0, FW_BOLD, 0, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET,
            OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE,
            choiceFont.c_str(), &Font);
    }

    void Hacks::InitializeMenuItems()
    {
        hack[WALLHACK].name = "WallHack and chams";
        hack[CUSTOM_CROSSHAIR].name = "Show custom crosshair";
        hack[NO_RECOIL].name = "No Recoil";
        hack[UNLIM_AMMO].name = "Unlimited equipment";
        hack[AUTO_FIRE].name = "Auto Fire";
        hack[HIDE_MENU].name = "Hide menu [INSERT]";
        hack[HIDE_MENU].on = false;
    }

    void Hacks::Draw_Text(LPCSTR TextToDraw, int x, int y, D3DCOLOR Color)
    {
        RECT rct = { x - 120, y + 120, y + 15 };
        Font->DrawTextA(NULL, TextToDraw, -1, &rct, DT_NOCLIP, Color);
    }

    void Hacks::DrawMenu(IDirect3DDevice9 *d3dDevice)
    {
        if (!hack[HIDE_MENU].on)
        {
            DrawFilledRectangle(55, 20, 200, 50, fontBlue, d3dDevice);
            DrawBorderBox(55, 20, 200, 50, 4, fontBlack, d3dDevice);
            DrawTextA("GAME", 190, 30, fontWhite);

            DrawFilledRectangle(30, 55, 250, (62 * MAX_MENU_ITEMS), fontBlue, d3dDevice);
            DrawBorderBox(30, 55, 250, (62 * MAX_MENU_ITEMS), 6, fontBlack, d3dDevice);

            int y = 40;
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MENU_ITEMS; i++)
            {
                DrawFilledRectangle(45, 30 + y, 220, 40, hack[i].on ? fontGreen : fontRed, d3dDevice);
                DrawBorderBox(45, 30 + y, 220, 40, 4, fontBlack, d3dDevice);
            }

            DrawTextA(hack[i].name.c_str(), 170, 39 + y, fontBlack);
            y + 50;
        }
    }

    void Hacks::DrawFilledRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, D3DCOLOR color, IDirect3DDevice9 *d3dDevice)
    {

    }

    void Hacks::DrawBorderBox(int x, int y, int width, int height, int thickness, D3DCOLOR color, IDirect3DDevice9 *d3dDevice)
    {

    }

    void Hacks::KeyboardInput()
    {

    }


CODE for Hacks.h

#include "d3d9.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

#define D3DHOOK_TEXTURES
#define MAX_MENU_ITEMS 6

#define WALLHACK 0
#define CUSTOM_CROSSHAIR 1
#define NO_RECOIL 2
#define UNLIM_AMMO 3
#define AUTO_FIRE 4
#define HIDE_MENU 5

/*DEFINITION FOR OUT CHAMS*/




class Hacks
{
public:
    int m_Stride;

    void Hacks::CreateFont(IDirect3DDevice9 *d3dDevice, std::string choiceFont);
    void Hacks::InitializeMenuItems();
    void Hacks::Draw_Text(LPCSTR TextToDraw, int x, int y, D3DCOLOR Color);
    void Hacks::DrawMenu(IDirect3DDevice9 *d3dDevice);
    void Hacks::DrawFilledRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height,D3DCOLOR color, IDirect3DDevice9 *d3dDevice);
    void Hacks::DrawBorderBox(int x, int y, int width, int height, int thickness, D3DCOLOR color, IDirect3DDevice9 *d3dDevice);
    void Hacks::KeyboardInput();

    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 texRed;
    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 textGreen;

    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 textBlue;
    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 textWhite;

    D3DVIEWPORT9 ViewPort;

    LPD3DXFONT Font;

    struct d3dMenuHack
    {
        bool on;
        std::string name;
    };

    d3dMenuHack hack[MAX_MENU_ITEMS];

};
```

YES, I have it set to multibyte characterset, and when I copied the code from the creator of the tutorial, it worked perfectly, but the thing is that they where the exact same code 100 % the same but one worked and the other did not, settings is set to win 32 and both debug and release gives errors.

this is tutorial code:

```
#include "hacks.h";


/*--------------CHEAT RELATED VARS-------------------*/

int MenuIndex = 0;

// Create a colour for the text 
D3DCOLOR fontRed = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);  
D3DCOLOR fontGreen = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 0, 255, 0);    
D3DCOLOR fontBlue = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 0, 42, 255);    
D3DCOLOR fontWhite = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);  
D3DCOLOR fontBlack = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);  
/*---------------------------------------------------*/


void Hacks::CreateFont(IDirect3DDevice9 *d3dDevice, std::string choiceFont)
{
        D3DXCreateFont( d3dDevice, 20, 0, FW_BOLD, 0, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, 
                OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, 
                choiceFont.c_str(), &m_font );
}


void Hacks::InitializeMenuItems()
{
    hack[WALLHACK].name = " WallHack and chams";
    hack[CUSTOM_CROSSHAIR].name = " Show custom crosshair";
    hack[NO_RECOIL].name = " No Recoil";
    hack[UNLIM_AMMO].name = " Unlimited equipment";
    hack[AUTO_FIRE].name = "All guns Automatic";
    hack[HIDE_MENU].name = " Hide hack [INSERT]";
    //make the hack visible by default
    hack[HIDE_MENU].on = false; //shows hack by default
}

void Hacks::DrawMenu(IDirect3DDevice9 *d3dDevice)
{
    if(!hack[HIDE_MENU].on)
    {
        //Add game name here, and put border around it
        DrawFilledRect( 55, 20, 200, 50, fontBlue, d3dDevice );
        DrawBorderBox(55, 20, 200, 50, 4, fontBlack, d3dDevice );
        Draw_Text("COD 4 MP hack", 190, 30, fontWhite);

        //draw back of our hack, transparent black
        DrawFilledRect( 30, 55, 250, (62*MAX_MENU_ITEMS),fontBlue, d3dDevice );
        //draw hack border
        DrawBorderBox(30, 55, 250, (62*MAX_MENU_ITEMS), 6/*was 6*/, fontBlack, d3dDevice );
        //Reset our time and update the text again in 2 secs
        int y = 40;
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_MENU_ITEMS; i ++)
        {
            //Draw each box's back colour, this will be based on whether the hack is on e.g.
            //red means off and green means on
            DrawFilledRect( 45, 30+y, 220, 40, hack[i].on ? fontGreen : fontRed, d3dDevice );

            //draw box Around Each hack item If the item is highlighted it will show with a white border
            DrawBorderBox(45, 30+y, 220, 40, 4, fontBlack, d3dDevice );

            //draw White border to show the user which hack item is currently selected
            if(MenuIndex == i)
            {
                DrawBorderBox(41, 26+y, 228, 48, 4, fontWhite, d3dDevice );
            }

            //Ternary at its finest, if the  hack is on we display the text colour in green
            //otherwise its green
            //Draw_Text(hack[i].KeyAssigned.c_str(), 160 , 32+y, fontWhite);
            Draw_Text(hack[i].name.c_str(), 170 , 39+y, fontBlack);
            //Draw_Text(hack[i].state. c_str(), 355 , 32+y, hack[i].on ? fontGreen : fontRed);
            //used to position the next item below by 30 height units
            y+= 50;
        }
        Draw_Text("Select using arrow keys", 170, ((62*MAX_MENU_ITEMS)+7), fontWhite);
        Draw_Text("Turn ON/OFF [END] key", 170, ((62*MAX_MENU_ITEMS)+27), fontWhite);
    }
}

void Hacks::DrawBorderBox( int x, int y, int w, int h, int thickness, D3DCOLOR Colour, IDirect3DDevice9 *pDevice)
{
    //Top horiz line
    DrawFilledRect( x, y, w, thickness,  Colour, pDevice );
    //Left vertical line
    DrawFilledRect( x, y, thickness, h, Colour, pDevice );
    //right vertical line
    DrawFilledRect( (x + w), y, thickness, h, Colour, pDevice );
    //bottom horiz line
    DrawFilledRect( x, y + h, w+thickness, thickness, Colour, pDevice );
}


//We receive the 2-D Coordinates the colour and the device we want to use to draw those colours with
void Hacks::DrawFilledRect(int x, int y, int w, int h, D3DCOLOR color, IDirect3DDevice9* dev)
{
    //We create our rectangle to draw on screen
    D3DRECT BarRect = { x, y, x + w, y + h }; 
    //We clear that portion of the screen and display our rectangle
    dev->Clear(1, &BarRect, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_TARGET, color, 0, 0);
}


void Hacks::Draw_Text(LPCSTR TextToDraw, int x, int y, D3DCOLOR Colour)
{
    // Create a rectangle to indicate where on the screen it should be drawn
    RECT rct = {x- 120, y, x+ 120, y + 15};

    // Draw some text 
    m_font->DrawText(NULL, TextToDraw, -1, &rct, DT_NOCLIP, Colour );
}


void Hacks::KeyboardInput()
{
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)&1)
    {
        if(MenuIndex > 0)
        {
            MenuIndex--;
        }
    }

    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)&1)
    {
        if(MenuIndex < MAX_MENU_ITEMS-1)
        {
            MenuIndex++;
        }
    }

    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END)&1)
    {
        hack[MenuIndex].on = !hack[MenuIndex].on;
        if(MenuIndex == NO_RECOIL)
        {
            //this is where we write memory, these are nop values
        }
        if(MenuIndex == UNLIM_AMMO)
        {
            //this is where we write memory
        }
    }

    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_INSERT)&1)
    {
        //TEXT DOESNT CHANGE as the hack is either hidden or not 
        //and if its hidden you cant tell the user to turn hack on(at least we wont)
        hack[HIDE_MENU].on = !hack[HIDE_MENU].on;
    }
}
```

Whati s weird about this is that in the video he uses DrawTextA, youtube; fleep Hacks.

but if I use Draw_Text it also gives error

Comment: The compiler plainly told you that `DrawTextA` does not take four arguments. It's [extremely easy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx) to verify that. As for `i` being declared, it's basic C++ knowledge that `i`'s scope is the for loop. Trying to do DirectX without basic knowledge of the language is going to waste everyone's time.

Comment: yes but when I copied and pasted the other code, it took 4 arguments, that the problem, something I dont understand

Comment: You mean `Hacks::Draw_Text`? That's a completely separate function.

Comment: I have this code and then I have the original code from the creator, and when I copy and paste that code, DrawTextA takes all those arguments

Comment: It almost seems like your question is "Why does the tutorial code work?" rather than "Why does my code not work?" Unfortunately, it's hard to answer that when the tutorial code (let alone which tutorial) isn't provided.

Answer (score 0):

DrawTextA takes 5 arguments, and you're only passing in 4.

```cpp
    INT DrawText(
  [in] LPD3DXSPRITE pSprite,
  [in] LPCTSTR      pString,
  [in] INT          Count,
  [in] LPRECT       pRect,
  [in] DWORD        Format,
  [in] D3DCOLOR     Color
);
```

The pSprite variable can be NULL, if you view the source code you're pasting he puts NULL as the first argument in every function call.  Just put a NULL in front of your other 4 arguments and it will compile.